# Why am I getting a SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making an app in React and am trying to import an async function I wrote from another file.

In database.js:

```js
async function SearchDatabase( ... ) {
    ... // connects to and queries a MongoDB database
}

...

module.exports = {
    SearchDatabase,
    ... // a few similar functions
}
```

And then in my React page, I'm importing it like this:

```js
import { SearchDatabase } from "../../backend/database"; // file path is correct
```

I'm not even using the SearchDatabase function yet, but my page refuses to load. In the console I get the error message `SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: SearchDatabase`. I googled this error and others seem to only be getting the problem when using a direct export, but this is not a direct export so I'm wondering what could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you mixing ES6 modules with CommonJS module syntax? Don't.

Comment: @Bergi if I convert database.js to use ES6 modules, I get another error I'm not sure how to approach. "TypeError: class heritage stream_1.Readable is not an object or null". I believe this happens because I can't import the mongodb module as an ES6 module.

And I can't convert React to use CommonJS modules.

Comment: Unless your code actually contains `extends stream_1.Readable`, it sounds like you are using some kind of transpiler that messes with the modules instead of just natively running them. Which of your classes does extend `Readable`?

Comment: None do, it seems to be in one of the modules. This project was generated yesterday from the nodejs Shopify app template and the database.js is really the only thing I've added to it, aside from some basic react pages/components and another REST endpoint. The template itself is mostly just a very basic React app.

Comment: Are you trying to import a backend database module into a React frontend module?

Comment: @ThomasSablik This was the solution. I moved the code to query the database into another REST endpoint and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks!